# Galaxy Tab S (retail mode) bricked - HELP!

Tags: samsung, unbricking

i have a problem with my Samsung Galaxy Tab S SM-T700 (WiFi) that I couldnt solve even after a lot of googling.

- Main Problem: It won't boot after I did some software updates (stuck on Samsung logo)
- Complications: Retail mode (MDM does not allow factory reset)

The data on the device is not important, it would be no problem to lose it, if I could somehow do a factory reset.

I tried re-flashing with the stock rom, but it still won't boot and still is in retail mode (actually, it "half-booted" once immediately after the flash, the OS started just to tell me it's not working and "has been quit").

Any ideas? Is it actually possible that there is no way to revive it?
Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

1. [Sammobile Firmware](https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/search/T700/)
2. [Odin](http://xda-university.com/as-a-user/android-flashing-guide)
3. For the next time, keep the retail mode in the developer section ALLWAYS ON